# gSoap + SSL : CRL & certificate name check

Tags: c++, openssl, gsoap

I'm developing a webservice using gSOAP with SSL support. It works fine as long as I COPY (that's it!) the code provided as gSOAP documentation. Trying to add some feature I collide with a lot of difficulties! I don't have a good knowledge of OpenSSL libraries, so I'm here to ask your help.
I should add a CRL list to check the certificate sent by the client. How can I do it? Moreover, I changed the function pointed by soap.fsslverify with this one:

```
int servlet_fsslverify(int ok, X509_STORE_CTX *store)
{
    ok = 1;
    char buf[1024];
    X509 *cert = X509_STORE_CTX_get_current_cert(store);
    fprintf(stderr, "SSL verify error or warning with certificate at depth %d: %s\n",
       X509_STORE_CTX_get_error_depth(store),
       X509_verify_cert_error_string(X509_STORE_CTX_get_error(store)));
    X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_issuer_name(cert), buf, sizeof(buf));
    fprintf(stderr, "certificate issuer %s\n", buf);
    X509_NAME_oneline(X509_get_subject_name(cert), buf, sizeof(buf));
    fprintf(stderr, "certificate subject %s\n", buf);
    /* Note: return 1 to continue, but unsafe progress will be terminated by OpenSSL */
    return ok;
}
```

It is called everytime a client tries to authenticate. As you can see, I'm able to check the fields in client's certificate, but I really don't know how to check if the particular certificate is present or not in a CRL.
That's all, thanks a lot to everyone would be so nice to answer.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution on the internet! Sorry I don't remember where, but I'll try to find it back and I'll edit this post - credits to the solver.
Code to be inserted right after server-context creation.

```
X509_STORE *store;  
store = SSL_CTX_get_cert_store(ServicePtr->ctx);
if (store) 
{
    X509_LOOKUP *lookup;
    X509_STORE_set_flags(store, X509_V_FLAG_CRL_CHECK);
    lookup = X509_STORE_add_lookup(store, X509_LOOKUP_file());
    if (lookup) 
    {
        if ( X509_load_crl_file(lookup, globals.pki_crl, X509_FILETYPE_ASN1) < 1 ) 
        {
            std::cerr << "CRL not found or invalid" << std::endl;
        }
    } 
    else 
    {
        std::cerr << "Unable to create a valid lookup" << std::endl;
    }
} 
else 
{
    std::cerr << "Unable to get X509_STORE" << std::endl;
}
```